# MessageDrivenBean instance identifier

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jms, message-driven-bean

Is it possible to get the identifier of the MDB instance that is executing?
I have a pool of MDB (e.g. 10) and I set in my messages the property JMSXGroupID in order to have the same MDB instance processing all the messages with same JMSXGroupID.
To check that I'd like to log an identifier of the current MDB instance: how can I get that information?

Comment: The MDB technology is stateless for performance considerations. If you want to use it in a statefull way you should turn back and refactor your architecture. You are on a wrong path. If you want just add an ID to them, you can do it in the @PostConstruct event handler, using a counter from the application scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such identifier according to EJB specification, although probably it may be achieved using your MDB vendor API.

You can always create unique MDB identifier in @PostConstruct method, but in my opinion it is not a good solution, as all beans in the pool should be treated the same way!

Maybe you could set JMSXGroupID as a message header, and use message selector in MDB to process it with given MDB implementation, so that there would be more than one bean listening on given queue ([example](http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/ejb-3/how-to-add-a-selector-with-mdb-30))?

Or you could create generic MDB bean which will extract mentioned previously  header and invoke EJB singleton bean with state you are willing to achieve per JMSXGroupID.

Comment: I already have a selector for different MDBs listening on the same queue. I'm using the JMSXGroupID in order to maintain order of arrival in the messages relative to the same entity; sending all messages relative to the same entity to the same MDB let me hope that they'll be processed in order, am I right?

Comment: So as ActiveMQ guaranties that all messages are handled by the same MDB instance, you can create unique identifier in @PostContruct method.

Comment: And if I use hashCode() method to identify different instances? Or all MDBs of the same Class share the same hashCode?

Comment: HashCode might work well, but if I were you I would use @PostConstruct and create more meaningful identifier.